# Oracle sql query for patients

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, oracle11g, window-functions

I have the following table.

W_TRANSFER_TXN

[image]

[image]

In It the the ward in dt and ward out dt is given. WRT_IN_DT and WRT_OUT_DT.

I need to find out the count of the number of patients in a particular date for a particular WRT_FROM_WARD_CD ward code.
It should be something like this:

[image]

One unique WRT_IP_NUM is a unique patient. How do I write a query to do that

Comment: Did you mean to tag [oracle-sqldeveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/oracle-sqldeveloper/info)? Your screenshots show [plsqldeveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/plsqldeveloper/info), although the question doesn't relate to either tool.

Answer (score 0):

**If** I follow you correctly, you can unpivot the columns to rows, then use a window sum:

```
select wrt_from_ward_cd, wrt_dt, 
    sum(val) over(partition by wrt_from_ward_cd order by wrt_dt) no_patients
from (
    select wrt_from_ward_cd, wrt_in_dt wrt_dt, 1 val from w_transfer_txn
    union all
    select wrt_from_ward_cd, wrt_out_dt, -1 val from w_transfer_txn
) t
```

This gives you the actual number of patients for every point in time. If you want to filter on a given date range, you need to nest the above query:

```
select *
from (
    select wrt_from_ward_cd, wrt_dt, 
        sum(val) over(partition by wrt_from_ward_cd order by wrt_dt) no_patients
    from (
        select wrt_from_ward_cd, wrt_in_dt wrt_dt, 1 val from w_transfer_txn
        union all
        select wrt_from_ward_cd, wrt_out_dt, -1 val from w_transfer_txn
    ) t
) t
where wrt_dt between date '2020-09-20' and date '2020-09-24'
```